# Application starts from Home Screen if app remains in the background for more than 30 seconds instead of showing the screen when it went to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, ios13

My iOS application is kind of messaging app, so user can send audio, video, images, etc. When user typing the message and app went background for more than 30 seconds then app launches from Home screen and all that messages, everything will be lost. Before 30 seconds app launches at the exact point where it went background. So how to do that same after 30 seconds also, at least I should maintain this state for 30 minutes.

Is using background process and schedule task will be a good method here in iOS 13+?

I particularly don't want to do anything on the background but when app comes from background to foreground within 30 minutes I want to maintain that state.

Comment: "at least I should maintain this state for 30 minutes." Then you need to use a lot less memory and other resources when you go into the background. The WatchDog is killing you for being a memory hog.

Comment: When I am going to background I am not running any background process , but how to run the app for 30 minutes in iOS 13+ , as per iOS 13+ terms app won't run more than 30 seconds in the background an

Answer (score 0):

### Messages Disappearing

Well, first of all, why are all the messages lost? if your trying to make a snapchat like experience where the messages disappear after you see them then that's fine but otherwise it might be worth adding a local storage for these messages using `CoreData`.

### Cause

The main issue, after a little while iOS will but an app to `sleep` so to say, in this scenario it will remove all temporary data within your app, this means when you re-open it it will start from the beginning, it does this to save memory.

### Solution

There are a few ways to solve this, you could use [State Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches)

For a beginner though this could be quite tricky as the documentation on it is quite sparse.

Another option would be to save the last screen in `UserDefaults` and then when the app re-launches you can use the value to push the last screen the user was on. For both these solutions though you will need a way to persist the messages and re-fetch them (a database) `CoreData` would probs be your best bet

I do personally think State Restoration is the best option especially since it sounds like that's exactly what you want to do:

> but when app comes from background to foreground within 30 minutes I want to maintain that state.

Comment: By using State Restoration it looks like we need to add all the controllers and what data we need to preserve , in that case we need to add all the controller if it has more than 10+ ? is it true